# Whitelist user IPs in Shiro

Tags: apache, facebook-graph-api, authentication, shiro

I would like to enable Facebook to crawl my website, however it needs user authentication. Facebook says one way to get around this is to whitelist their ips. I am using Apache Shiro and I know that you can get client's ip by calling getHost from BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter, however I do not know how to let certain ip addresses past the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have to build a custom implementation of Shrio's

```
org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.AuthenticatingFilter
```

Minimally, you will have to customize BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter by extending it and adding logic to skip the BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter if the request is coming from a whitelisted IP address.

```
package com.acme.web.filter.authc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

public class WhitelistedBasicHttpAuthenticationFilter extends BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter {

    private Set<String> whitelist = Collections.emptySet();

    public void setWhitelist(String list) {
        whitelist = new HashSet<String>();
        Collections.addAll(whitelist, list.split(",")); //make sure there are no spaces in the string!!!!
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isEnabled (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        if (whitelist.contains(request.getRemoteAddr())) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.isEnabled(request, response);
    }
}
```

In your 'shiro.ini'

```
authc=com.acme.web.filter.authc.WhitelistedBasicHttpAuthenticationFilter
authc.whitelist=192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.2.3
```